# How to use Suppose for future, present , past imaginary situation?

Tags: sentence-construction

A) Suppose in the future we pick the Royal Princess .

A2)  Suppose in the future we picked the Royal Princess .

B) Suppose in the past we picked the Royal Princess .

B2) Suppose in the past we pick the Royal Princess .

C) Suppose we pick the Royal Princess .

C2) Suppose we picked the Royal Princess .

Please help correct with above sentences if they are correctly formed using suppose in all tences.

I mainly want to understand that can we use verb + ed or not  when have to say imagination.

Comment: What do you *mean*, by, for example, *Suppose in the past we pick the Royal Princess?* You can't adverbially apply ***in the past*** to imperative ***You*** or ***Let us** suppose...,* which is inherently a ***present tense*** reference (a suggestion that the supposition should be made ***now***, at time of speaking). And ***we pick*** must be either a Present or Future reference. What exactly are the time-based relationships you're trying to convey here?

Answer (score 0):

> A) Suppose in the future we pick the Royal Princess.

The implication here is really that we will not be picking the Royal Princess now, and perhaps not for some time, it's a discussion aren't potentially doing this in the future.

> A2) Suppose in the future we picked the Royal Princess.

This is very similar to the above, but projects to a point in time after we have picked the Royal Princess, and places the emphasis on that.

> B) Suppose in the past we picked the Royal Princess.

This one would be used if we were suggesting that picking the Royal Princess in the past would have had different consequences to picking the Royal Princess now and about to illustrate a difference.

To reflect on the consequences of the past decision now, we would say:

> Suppose we had picked the Royal Princess.
>
> B2) Suppose in the past we pick the Royal Princess.

This one doesn't make any sense. We could say:

> Suppose in the past we had picked the Royal Princess.

This is similar to B, but with a shift in emphasis similar to the one described in A2.

> C) Suppose we pick the Royal Princess.

We are considering picking the Royal Princess now, and are considering what would happen.

> C2) Suppose we picked the Royal Princess.

This is very similar to C, but with a shift in emphasis similar to the one described in A2.